# Issues in setting UIButton title in its click event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ibaction, sender

I'm trying to change the title of a button when the user press on it with the following code:

```
- (IBAction) hideKB: (UIButton *) sender {
     sender.titleLabel.text = @"↓";
}
```

But when I click the app crashes and I can't understand why.

Removing the sender stuff, the button works with no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct method signature for an action is

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender
```

Your app is crashing because your object is being sent a message it doesn't understand.

Try replacing your code with something along the lines of:

```
- (IBAction)hideKB:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button setTitle:@"↓" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

As you may notice I've also changed the line that sets the button title. This is because you should never manipulate a `UIButton`'s `titleLabel` property directly, but rather you should be using the appropriate setter method as shown above.

**Edit:** To clarify, most controls will allow you to use dot notation to edit the `text` property of their `titleLabel`. However, `UIButton` instances support different titles (as well as images and background images) depending on the state they're in.

If you're wondering why a `UIButton` could be in one of several different states, a good example you often see is buttons that are "greyed out". What this means is that those buttons are in the `UIControlStateDisabled` state. You can find a list of all the possible states for a control [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState).

Comment: However I really can't get the difference between calling the setter method or using the dot notation…
Also some doubt about the "State", what that refers to?

Comment: I've also edited by answer to clarify what it means for a button to have a state. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with:

```
[(UIButton *)sender setTitle: @"↓"" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

For more information, you can refer to [setTitle:forState: in UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW7)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 - (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
```

e.g.

```
 [sender setTitle:"↓" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```